# JQuery change checkbox state from Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have a small problem in my code.
I have a function, which require loadData AJAX page.
This result puts checkboxes on my pages. (this is OK)

Now I want when I click a checkbox, executes an AJAX request is to change a value in the database (this is also ok).

The problem is:
When I click on a checkbox (unchecked) it tick and execute the ajax, once the ajax executed, the box is uncheck all alone.

I made several tests and I realized that the problem occurs only when the checked boxes from an Ajax request.

Note : I've tried to add the $(selector).attr('checked', true) and false, but nothing work.

Jquery (The Problem is in loadData Function when  Ajax is executed, the checkbox uncheck alone) :

```
 $(document).ready(function()  {
    $('#TableContainer .RCkbox').live('click',function(){

        var idOperation = 550;
        if($(this).is(":checked")){

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "includes/ajax/OperationRapprochement.php",
                data: "sessionId=" + <?php echo $User->getId(); ?> + "&AccountNumber=" + <?php echo $compte->getId(); ?> + "&idOperation=" + idOperation + "&action=rapproche",
                success: function(msg)
                {
                    //TODO  

                }
            });
        }
        else{

                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "includes/ajax/OperationRapprochement.php",
                data: "sessionId=" + <?php echo $User->getId(); ?> + "&AccountNumber=" + <?php echo $compte->getId(); ?> + "&idOperation=" + idOperation + "&action=derapproche",
                success: function(msg)
                {
                      //TODO

                }
            });
       }
    });


    function loadData(){
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/ajax/test.php",
            data: "sessionId=" + <?php echo $User->getId(); ?> + "&AccountNumber=" + <?php echo $compte->getId(); ?>,
            success: function(msg){
                    $("#TableContainer").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){
                           $("#TableContainer").html(msg);
                    });
            }
        });
    }

    loadData();
});
```

I've make video to show you the problem in action : http://youtu.be/nG9XF2f4M18

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** Answer was updated from the information I got in the comments **

I found the problem in your files.

The thing is that you use the event ".ajaxComplete". 
If you read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) correctly, it says that the event gets call everytime an ajax call gets made.

So since you make an ajax call when you click on a checkbox, when you receive the result, the callback in the loadData function gets called again meaning that it executes `$("#TableContainer").html(msg);` again... in other words, it replaces the content again. 
That's why you lose the checked checkboxes.

All you have to change in your code is remove the events `.ajaxComplete` since you don't need them.

This is your code:

```
function loadData(){
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/ajax/test.php",
        data: "number=" + number,
        success: function(msg)
        {
            $("#TableContainer").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
                $("#TableContainer").html(msg);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

It should be:

```
function loadData(){
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/ajax/test.php",
        data: "number=" + number,
        success: function(msg)
        {
                $("#TableContainer").html(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

Same thing for your other 2 ajax requests. 
The code in success gets executed when it receives a result.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer, but the click method is been attached to the checkbox (i've test with an alert("ok"), and it's work when I click on the checkbox)
I've also test with checkbox generated by a for loop and no problem. the problem happen only when the checkbox come from ajax response.

Comment: ok I get it now. In the code you have made for the video, do you have something that replaces the //TODO? Also, can you give access to a link where all the html code is? By the way, you should declare the function loadData outside of the document.ready.

Comment: Yes, something replaces the //TODO, it's a dialog of JQuery, but with or without that is the same thing. Only if I remove the $.ajax... the checkbox work. The problem happen only when I call an ajax request On Click on a Ajax response's element.
I change the loadData Function to outside of the document.ready, nothing change.
Thanks for your help

Comment: That's a really strange behavior. I would need the see an example of the resulting HTML/Javascript to help you out.

Comment: I've Upload 3 php pages : http://depositfiles.com/files/rzxlm6jzf
Index.php contains the Javascript and HTML (don't worry about the PHP Class, they included by another page).
test.php is the AJAX request to generate the checkbox (first request)
OperationRapprochement.php is the AJAX request called by the checkbox click.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Many many Thanks @ComputerArts This is the solution. Again Thank You :)